# Who am I? What's my job?

Tags: riddle

Each day I wake up, my hand reaches the window's handle
so stale air can leave the bedroom. 
I then get up and think for a while about my condition.
I have to work. I shake the sheets,
close the window next to my bed,
open the one next to my desk, and
I take a deep breath and sit in my chair.
Now things become painful.
Sun is burning my eyes,
I close the blinds, it's getting hot in here.
I need to go but my legs hurt,
I can't get on my feet again.
Try harder I say to myself,
or I will be late.
I'm almost done when I faint.
That's it for my day, next morning 
I'll wake up again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is you are a

> Four stroke car engine

and your job is to

> move a car

my hand reaches the window handle, so stale air can leave the bedroom

> exhaust. Spent air/fuel is discarded from the engine.

I shake the sheets, close the window next to my bed, open the one next to my desk, I take a deep breath and sit in my chair

> intake. Fuel and air are taken in for another cycle.

now things become painful. Sun is burning my eyes, I close the blinds, it's getting hot in here...I'm almost done when I faint.

> compression/combustion. The intake valves are closed, and the mixture is compressed. Combustion and the resulting turning of the piston generates mechanical work, which forces the car to move (even though it is really heavy and doesn't really want to.

That's it for my day, next morning I'll wake up again.

> Next cycle

I have to work

> engine converts energy in fuel to work.

Comment: +1 you are almost correct! There are hints telling precisely who I am. Anyway you found the biggest part!

Comment: rot 13: znlor vg'f n gjb-fgebxr ratvar, fvapr vagnxr/rkunhfg ner qrfpevorq gbtrgure naq gura pbzcerffvba/pbzohfgvba ner qrfpevorq gbtrgure?

Comment: rot13: ab vg'f abg n gjb fgebxr ratvar!